Motivating spinors via the Dirac equation
I'm trying to motivate spin through Dirac's equation. So far, here is what I understand:
Upon trying to take the "square root" of the space-time Laplacian (i.e. find an operator such that $D \circ D = \nabla$ on some class of maps), one finds one needs
$$\gamma(e_i) \gamma(e_j) +\gamma(e_j) \gamma(e_i) = 2\eta_{ij}$$
from the ansatz $D = \sum \gamma(e_i) \partial_i$ in which $\{e_i \}$ are an orthonormal frame at some point in Minkowski space time. Since this is  physics, one would like the gamma symbols to be matrices and thus one needs a matrix representation of the Clifford algebra $Cl(1,3)$ (or maybe $Cl(3,1)$). Now the relevant structure theorem tells us $Cl(1,3) \cong \mathrm{End}(\mathbb{C}^4)$ as an algebra thus leading us to define the space of Dirac spinors as $\Delta_{Dirac} = \mathbb{C}^4$ as then we have an apropriate space of maps carrying the desired representation.
Now this whole construction above is sort of a local coordinates/chosen gauge construction. To really get a Dirac operator which is geometrical, we need to figure out how two local descriptions glue together. So another ortho. frame at the same point may be taken as $\{\tilde{e}_j \}$. Following the same procedure as above, they (the associated observer) may write
$$D = \sum \tilde{\gamma}(\tilde{e}_j) \tilde{\partial_j}$$
This observer also understands the space of spinors must be $\mathbb{C}^4$ and seeks a matrix representation of the same Clifford algebra. Now the representation in the sense of mathematics is the same: it is simply the identity map. But apparently, the construction of the Clifford algebra somehow is not the same.
I am confused. Can someone explain section 2.1 of these notes would finish the above argument?
Update: I thun. It seems one recognizes the whole Clifford algebra as a "geometric/invariant" object and thus deduces the following at the level of Clifford algebra:
$$\tilde{\gamma}(\tilde{e_j}):= \gamma (\tilde{e_j}) = \gamma(e_i) \Lambda_{ij}$$
using the linearity of the Clifford map. Now taking identity on both sides to progress to the spin representation, the matrix representations must be similar as the Clifford algebra elements are equal. i.e. there must exist some $S \in Mat(\mathbb{C}^4)$ such that
$$S \tilde{\gamma}_j S^{-1} = \gamma_{j} \Lambda_{ij}$$
now somehow we can deduce the Dirac field must transform by this $S$ matrix? (which we see must be an element of a spin group due to the double cover of the Lorentz group?)
